# What is a HTTP Error 414 Request URI too long

Tags: c#, azure

I am working with windows azure table storage. I am trying to implement a insertorreplace operation on the tablestorage table. Like this:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#insert-or-replace-entity

It´s working fine when i have small string value to retrieve from the table but when i have long string values i get this error.

"The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Long."

I gave googled it but i dont understand what it means. The best explanation i found is this:  http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E414.html

Can someone help me understand this problem?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248061 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is there any way around it?